# Why some GPU micro-benchmarks contain page size for measure global memory access and L1/L2 cache access?

Tags: gpu, microbenchmark, page-size

I am trying to run a [GPU micro-benchmark](http://www.stuffedcow.net/research/cudabmk) to get latency of global memory access and L1/L2 access of Jetson TK1. But in the micro-benchmark, it contains page size as one of parameters when using pointer-chasing code.

Does anyone know why the benchmark include page size when measuring memory access latency?

Comment: Maybe ... because different page sizes lead to different performance numbers?